# weird error with metamask

Tags: metamask

While I am trying to call a function using metamask i've got this error :

> error: Error: TypeError: senderAddress.toLowerCase is not a function
>   at
>   chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:65204:74
>   at HookedWalletSubprovider.getAccounts
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:3806:11)
>   at HookedWalletSubprovider.validateSender
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/background.js:65202:8)
>   at HookedWall....

Comment: `toLowerCase()` is a method that is on String objects, so that error would imply that `senderAddress` is not a string, which the extension is expecting it to be at that point. Did you get logged out of MetaMask and your sender address was no longer accessible?

Comment: excactly that was my problem the address was not defined. if you write this as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Sure thing; glad it was a simple fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toLowerCase()` is a method that is on String objects, so that error would imply that `senderAddress` is not a string, which the extension is expecting it to be at that point. Possibly you get logged out of MetaMask and your sender address was no longer accessible? Or you were trying to manually trigger something and sent a bad input as the sender.